# How to reload data in tabulator data table?

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to load a dynamic data using [tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) I can generate table and data using this code:

```
 $("#example-table").tabulator({
        layout:"fitColumns",

        columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
    ],
      });
      var tabledata = [
      {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
      {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
      {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
      {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
      {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
      ];

    //  $("#example-table").tabulator("setData", []);

      $("#example-table").tabulator("setData", tabledata);
```

But when I am trying to reload same data onclick function I am getting error:

```
 Options Error - Tabulator does not allow options to be set after initialization unless there is a function defined for that purpose
```

So my question is how to empty data of table and reload new data or same data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to populate your table with new data for that you need to empty the data of current table for that you need to see this link:

[Tabulator Discussion](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/358)

Here olifolkerd is saying that you could either reinitialise the grid, by destroying it and recreating it using:

```
 $("#example-table").tabulator("destroy");
 $("#example-table").tabulator({...});
```

If you want to check if table is empty of not use this jquery to check if tabulator data is active or not:

```
 var j = $( "#example-table" ).hasClass( "tabulator" )
     if (j) {
        $("#example-table").tabulator("destroy");

      }
//set new columns
      $("#example-table").tabulator("setColumns", res["column"]);

      //set new data
      $("#example-table").tabulator("setData", res["data"]);
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer on this is a bit overkill, you can call the ***setData*** and ***setColumns*** functions at any after the table is created. there is no need to destroy it first

```
//update columns and data without destroying the table
$("#example-table").tabulator("setColumns", res["column"]);
$("#example-table").tabulator("setData", res["data"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for creating and still maintaining this awesome library. Special thank for efforts to use pure/vanilla JS (ES6) as of version 4 that makes it easy to integrate it with React and other popular JS frameworkls. There is massive improvement in it compared to older version, that I turn my attention back to Tabulator after using ag-Grid community edition. I am planning to use Tabulator for new modules in my app that need multi-level row grouping, as it works expected in my test app. Thank again, author.

Answer (score 1):

A function is defined for that purpose. You can use replaceData method with array of data. Or you can clear table data and add a fresh dataset.

```
table.clearData();
table.updateOrAddData([{id:1, name:"bob"}, {id:3, name:"steve"}])
.then(function(rows){
    //rows - array of the row components for the rows updated or added
    //run code after data has been updated
})
.catch(function(error){
    //handle error updating data
});

//Replace Data
table.replaceData(tableData)
.then(function(){
    //run code after table has been successfuly updated
})
.catch(function(error){
    //handle error loading data
});
```

more on this here.

```
[http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/update][1]
```